# uvicorn error: unrecognized arguments: main:app --reload

Tags: uvicorn

- env `venv`
- code

  ```py
  import argparse 

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--host", type=str, default="0.0.0.0", help='default Ip')
  parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=18002, help='default port')
  ```

  ```py
  import uvicorn
  from fastapi import FastAPI

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      import uvicorn
      app = create_app()

      uvicorn.run(app, host=str(args.host), port=int(args.port))
  ```
- bootstrap

  ```bash
  python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
  ```
- error

  ```
  error: unrecognized arguments: main:app --reload
  ```

i try use `uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=18002)`

but problem still raise, has anyone else had similar problems and can offer some help?

Answer (score 0):

First, the options after `uvicorn.run` should be `file_name:function_name` format, not the variable_name (yours is `app`). For example:

*`main.py`*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

async def create_app() -> FastAPI:
   # Create your app and routers
   ...
   return app
```

then, in your terminal, run:
`uvicorn main:create_app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 18002`

As I know, run normal uvicorn can't parse the args, you should create new file `run.py`, parse args via python first then run the uvicorn with `create_app` fuction from file `main.py` for e.g:

*`run.py`*

```
import argparse
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--host", type=str, default="0.0.0.0", help="Hosting default: 0.0.0.0"
    )
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=18002)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    uvicorn.run(
        "main:create_app", host=args.host, port=args.port
    )
```

then, run `python run.py`